# parent radio button can enable and disable child radio button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

When one parent radio button is click, its children is enabled, and when it is deselected, it would be disabled. what will i do with my jquery codes to disable the child when the parent is deselected?

```
 <body>
<p><input type="radio" name="educationalqualification" disabled="true" id="bdmain"  />Bachelor's Degree</p>
<ul>
<li><label><input type="radio" id="bd1" name="bd" disabled="true"/>Four Years</label>    </li>
<li><label><input type="radio" id="bd2" name="bd" disabled="true"/>Exceeding Four Years</label></li>
</ul>
 <p><input type="radio" id="scmain" name="educationalqualification"   disabled="true"/>Special Courses</p>
 <ul>
 <li><label><input type="radio" id="sc1" name="sc" disabled="true"/>3- years post secondary course</label></li>
 <li><label><input type="radio" id="sc2" name="sc" disabled="true"/>Special courses (Non degree)</label></li>
</ul>
</body>
```

help me with my jquery please. thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#bdmain").click(function(){
        $("#bd1").attr('disabled', false);
        $("#bd2").attr('disabled', false);
    });
    $("#scmain").click(function(){
        $("#sc1").attr('disabled', false);
        $("#sc2").attr('disabled', false);
    });
});
```

Comment: disabled input no more respond to user interaction, so your click handler is not fired here. BTW, hard time to figure out what could be the relevant behaviour you are looking for. Why disabling elements if you want them to be enable on click?!

Comment: Oops, sorry. my question is that, what can i do with my jquery codes that will disable the child radio when the parent is deselected

Comment: why are you doing `disabled to false` try doing `enabled to true`...

Answer (score 0):

Use prop instead of attr for bool properties.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#bdmain").click(function(){
        $("#bd1").prop ('disabled', false);
        $("#bd2").prop ('disabled', false);
    });
    $("#scmain").click(function(){
        $("#sc1").prop ('disabled', false);
        $("#sc2").prop ('disabled', false);
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the use of .prop? and it does not disabled when deselected. thanks. cheers.

Comment: @user3367225 what about reading DOC instead of asking for it?!